# VoiceOver can access element behind modal even when accessibilityViewIsModal on modal is set

Tags: ios, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have a custom view that is a popup and it has `accessibilityViewIsModal = true`, but VoiceOver can still focus on the elements behind the modal. Is there any other way to keep the focus inside of the popup until the user dismiss the popup?